# subset() argument treated as object in R ( Object not found )

Tags: r

I am trying to get a sum of column *size* where the name of another column (side) is either B or S. This works fine in the RStudio Console but when I try running it from the terminal it tells me that

- **Error in subset.default(book, side == "B") : object 'side' not found**

```
book.tv <- function(book) {

    bid = sum(subset(book, side == "B")["size"])
    ask = sum(subset(book, side == "S")["size"])

    return(list(bid, ask))
}
```

Why is "side" treated as an object, when it's actually an function parameter?

*Example of a read in file (book):*

```
  side price size
1   S    52   71
2   S    51   88
3   S    49   55
4   B    44   18
>
```

Comment: Can you put a chunk of `book` in your question, so people can play with?

Comment: The book is just a read.csv file

Comment: Are you sure `book` has a column called `side` and `size`?

Comment: Anything else you can share? How are you calling `book.tv` with your data?

Comment: Running `book.tv(book)` does not give me any errors.  Start a fresh session of R and try it again.

Comment: Regarding your question "Why is "side" treated as an object, when it's actually an function parameter?". `side` is not a function parameter (or, as I would prefer to say, an argument), it is an object that you use in a function argument. The actual argument that you pass to the function is `side == "B"`.

Comment: The data and function you present work for me. I get the result of 18 and 214.